# LINQ Full Outer Join on Date Range

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am working on a report that determines when notices should have been sent. Table 1 contains data used to determine when a notice should have been sent, Table 2 contains data on all notices sent. I need to be able to show a table that links a notice required to a notice sent, shows when no notice was sent, and shows when a notice was sent without supporting documentation. A notice needs to be sent within 2 weeks. I need to be able to do a full outer join like below with and addition of two date fields, table2.date being within 2 weeks of table1.date. On an inner join I could just use a where clause, but what do I do on a outer join to not lose records that do not have a match?

```
var leftOuterJoin =
    from first in table1
    join last in table2 on new {A = first.ID, B = first.Type} equals new {last.ID, last.Type} into temp
    from last in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        first.ID,
        Col1 = first.col1,
        Col2 = first.col2,
        Col3 = last?.Col3,
        Col4 = last?.col4
    };
var rightOuterJoin =
    from last in table2
    join first in table1 new {last.ID, last.Type} equals new {A = first.ID, B = first.Type} into temp
    from first in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        last.ID,
        Col1 = first?.col1,
        Col2 = first?.col2,
        Col3 = last.Col3,
        Col4 = last.col4
    };
var fullOuterJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);
```

Comment: You should be able to add `where` after each second `from...DefaultIfEmpty()` to filter by the date: `where (last.date-first.date).TotalDays / 7 <= 14`.

Comment: This isn't working because first or last will be null when there is no match and throws an exception.

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?